# How do I rotate objects 180 degrees on android?

Tags: java, android, rotation, png, imagebutton

How can I rotate .png imageButton 180 degrees? I try this with animation but when the animation end, turning it started. Thanks..

Comment: Can you please clarify. Do you mean that when the animation call ends the image starts rotating/turning? Also please share you code, it will make things easier!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use with an `ImageView` and with API>=11

```
mImageView.setRotation(angle);
```

In XML attribute you can use `android:rotation="90"`

You can also do it with `Matrix`

(Assuming `imageView`, `angle`, `pivotX` & `pivotY` are already defined)

```
 Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);   //required
    matrix.postRotate((float) angle, pivotX, pivotY);
    imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding this:

```
yourAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
```

And if you want the real view rotate (change original position), using `ObjectAnimator`